# Data is not being written in Firebase Realtime Database due to some swcurity rules I have changed

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have the firebase realtime database structure as follows:

```
users
   |
   users_init
            |
            [userID1]
                   |
                   name

                   visit_count
             |
             [userID2]
                    |
                    name

                    visit_count
```

I am developing an Android app.
What I want is that "name" can be written ONLY BY THE USER and "visit_count" will be updated when someone visits the profile so I am trying to update "visit_count" from the client app so It WILL BY UPDATED BY ANYONE.
The firebase security rule is as follows

```
"rule":{
   "user_init":{
       "$uid":{
           "name":{
              ".write":"$uid === auth.uid",
              ".read": true
            }
            "visit_count":{
                ".write":true,
                 ".read": true
            }
      }
  }
}
```

But this is not working.USER AUTHENTICATION IS FINE.
NO DATA IS BEING WRITTEN IN THE DATABASE.
WHAT WRONG AM I DOING?
Please Help,
Thank you in advance

Comment: @sayaan , How are you updating **visit_count** using your client app ? Show me the code.

Comment: I am not with my laptop right now so I'll not be able to show the exact code but I can explain.   Inside onCreate() i have written  a method to increament 'visitCount' ( Transaction). So whenever the profile is visited visitCount increaments

Comment: Just a hint: be careful about using all uppercase too much. That is perceived as SCREAMING - and rejected by most people.

Comment: Thank you.I'll keep that in mind